How to Start PCB Design for a Simple DDR3 RAM Module?
I'm new to designing PCBs involving DDR3 RAM, and I need some guidance on how to get started. This is a simple project, but since DDR3 involves high-speed signals, I want to ensure I'm approaching it correctly from the beginning.
Here are the basics of my project:
DDR3 RAM specs: don't know .
PCB Layers: Planning for a [number of layers] layer PCB.
Design Software: Altium.
I'm a bit lost on where to start. My questions are:

What are the fundamental steps to begin a DDR3 PCB design?

What should I focus on first—schematic design, trace impedance calculations, or routing strategy?

Are there any beginner-friendly resources or guides for understanding DDR3 signal requirements and layout best practices?

Is it better to prototype with an evaluation board before attempting the PCB design from scratch?


I'd appreciate any advice, resources, or tips from those who have experience working with DDR3 RAM.

Are you otherwise familiar with high speed signals, signal integrity, differential signals, and high speed PCB design, but lacking how to apply that knowledge specifically to DDR3 technology? I mean, I would not call making a DDR3 RAM module "simple" by any metric.

Grab a reference design from your supplier of choice. Study it, Copy, adapt, simulate, build, test. Understand all the issues that might arise - SI, PI, Thermal, mechanical. High speed design is not beginner friendly.

Focus first on understanding a reference design from a reputable memory manufacturer. Then modify if required.
